# Joining tables to fill lists of entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA and Hibernate, but my need is too complicated to build a HQL, at least for me.
I decided to use native SQL.
I need to get some records/entities with their child lists but, i need to filter childs, i do not want all the childs.
Is this possible?

For example i have three tables like

conversation_table:
id

mail_table:
id, conversation_id, sender_id

user_table:
id, married_bool

I need `conversation` entities having lists that filled by `mail`s those are send by married users.

I tried so far

```
Select * from conversation_table join mail_table on ( mail_table.sender_id=user_table.id and user_table.married_bool=true)
```

I am getting an error like:

```
user_table is unknown
```

I tried

```
Select * from (conversation_table, user_table, mail_table) join mail_table on ( mail_table.sender_id=user_table.id and user_table.married_bool=true)
```

I am getting

```
mail_table is non unique table/alias
```

This is only a light example,  also need to fill some entity lists of mail entity in other tables for example recipient_table, i think i have to add join clauses for filling these too in native query, am i right? Also i am getting 'not known'/'non unique alias' errors, when try this additional join clauses.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM conversation_table CT
   JOIN mail_table MT
      ON CT.Id = MT.conversation_id
   JOIN user_id UI
      ON MT.sender_id=UI.id
WHERE UT.married_bool = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Hibernate ORM for this query they Criteria Query is the best approach for this. Recently, i have the same requirement and have used Criteria only.